# Why does angular sees my class as a module?

Tags: angular, class, module

I have a simple class:

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    token?: string;
    role?: string;
    dateCreated?: number;
}
```

and when I import it in a component, like so:

```
import { User } from "src/app/models/user";
```

, I am getting the error:

```
Cannot find module '../models/user'.
```

but this class User is not a module, it is just a helper class to put my user data in. How can I tell angular that this is just a simple class, and not a module?

Comment: It's in the meaning of a Typescript module, not angular module. Just make sure that the file exists and that you import it properly `import {User} from '../models/user'` where `../user.ts` is the file from above. And mind case for the file name. Edit:  Where is your component file located? Try using relative path when importing your file

Comment: hi. that worked. If you put it as answer, I  could accept it as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the meaning of a Typescript module, not angular module.

Just make sure that the file exists and that you import it properly using the correct path relatively to the component's path.

```
import {User} from '../models/user'
```

where `../models/user.ts` is the file from above.

And mind case for the file name if you are on Linux